# The value of checkbox is wrong in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net.  I want to show unchecked checkbox but in the browser the status of the checkbox is true and I have set the checkbox.checked= false in serverside code but it displays checked in the browser.

Here is my code

```
   {<asp:CheckBox ID="SendNotificationCheckBox" runat="server" Checked="false" Enabled="false"    oncheckedchanged="SendNotificationCheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>}
```

I tried this piece of code in server side:

```
{ protected void SendNotificationCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (SendNotificationCheckBox.Checked == true)
     {
         NotificationPanel.Visible = true;
         NotificationMessageTextBox.Text = "Business Listing Named:" + BusinessNameLabel.Text.Trim() + " Will Be Expired On" + NextVerificationDateLabel.Text.Trim() + ".Contact Us To Renew it.";
     }
     else if (SendNotificationCheckBox.Checked == false)
     {
         NotificationPanel.Visible = false;
     }
 }}
```

Comment: pls post code which you have tried.

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: It may depend on when you're setting the whole `Checked` property during the page/cotnrol life-cycle...

Comment: Did you do something in accordance with the checkbox in `PageLoad()` ??

Comment: Yes sir, i have Initilise the checkboxes.Checked to false.

Comment: Its not enabled, there should be more code accessing that checkbox

Comment: In the PageLoad() I have set the checked=false and enabled =true.

Comment: then place the checkbox related code in if(!IsPostBack){ SendNotificationCheckBox.checked=false and SendNotificationCheckBox.enabled =true }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't what you asked, but I think JavaScript / JQuery would be best for this kind of things. Place the following code in the head of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleVisibility(cb) {
        var x = document.getElementById("NotificationPanel");
        x.style.display = cb.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>
```

and in your Checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="SendNotificationCheckBox" runat="server" Checked="false" onclick="toggleVisibility(this);"/>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="NotificationPanel" style="display: none;">
    skjhaskjf
</asp:Panel>
```

or if You want to use JQuery, add this in your Head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SendNotificationCheckBox").click(function () {
            $(this).is(':checked') ? $("#NotificationPanel").show() :
                $("#NotificationPanel").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

and your checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="SendNotificationCheckBox" runat="server" Checked="false"/>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="NotificationPanel" style="display: none;">
    skjhaskjf
</asp:Panel>
```

Here is the solution to your problem as you wanted.
You were unchecking the textbox and disabling it in `PageLoad`. If you do that, every time when the control comes to the server, `PageLoad` will be executed, and the checkbox will be be disabled. and after executing the pageload, the event 'SendNotificationCheckBox_CheckedChanged' will be executed.

Since the Checkbox is unchecked in the pageload, the code you have written if Checkbox is checked will be of no use. So, you have to check whether the page is loading for the first time. If so, Uncheck the checkbox or else don't.
You have to Do that by Checking for `IsPostBack` property by

```
If(!IsPostBack)
{
    CheckBoxID.Checked=false;
    CheckBoxID.Enabled=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is inside update panel,

then you need to update your update panel..